# Java EE: Why do we need to know about Concurrency?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, concurrency, transactions

I am extracting the following lines from the famous book - Mastering Enterprise JavaBeans™ 3.0.

> Concurrent Access and Locking:Concurrent access to data in the database is always protected by transaction isolation, so you need not design additional concurrency controls to protect your
>   data in your applications if transactions are used appropriately. Unless you make specific provisions, your entities will be protected by container-managed transactions using the isolation levels that are configured for your persistence provider and/or EJB container’s transaction service. However, it is important to understand the concurrency control requirements and semantics of your applications.

Then it talks about Java Transaction API, Container Managed and Bean Managed Transaction, different TransactionAttributes, different Isolation Levels. It also states that -

> The Java Persistence specification defines two important features that can be
>   tuned for entities that are accessed concurrently:
>   1.Optimistic locking using a version attribute
>   2.Explicit read and write locks

Ok - I read everything and understood them well. But the question comes in which scenario I need the use all these techniques? If I use Container Managed transaction and it does everything for me why I need to bother about all these details? I know the significance of TransactionAttributes (REQUIRED, REQUIRES_NEW) and know in which cases I need to use them, but what about the others? More specifically -

1. Why do I need Bean Managed transaction?
2. Why do we need Read and Write Lock on Entity classes?
3. Why do we need version attribute?

For Q2 and Q3 - I think Entity classes are not thread safe and hence we need locking over there. But database is managed at the EJB class by the JTA API (as stated in the first para), and then why do we need to manage the Entity classes separately? I know how the Lock and Version works and why they are required. But why they are coming into the picture since JTA is already present?

Can you please provide any answer to them? If you give me some URLs even that will be very highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Food for thought -> How would you design a transaction management system that could maintain the ACID properties at the application level? For example: A transaction management system for a filesystem

Comment: Thanks Satadru for your points to ponder about. I will go through more books to make my doubts clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need locking because entity classes are not thread-safe. Entities must not be shared between threads, that's all.

Your database comes with ACID guarantees, but that is not always sufficient, and you sometimes nees to explicitely lock rows to get what you need. Imagine the following scenarios:

- transaction A reads employee 1 from database
- transaction B reads employee 1 from database
- transaction A sets employee 1 salary to 3000
- transaction B sets employee 1 salary to 4000
- transaction A commits
- transaction B commits

The end result is that the salary is 4000. The user that started transaction A is completely unaware that even though he set the salary to 3000, another user, concurrently, set it to 4000. Depending on which transaction writes last, the end result is different (and thus unpredictable). That's the kind of situation that can be avoided using optimistic locking.

Next scenario: you want to generate purely sequential invoice numbers, without lost values and without duplicates. You could imagine reading and incrementing a value in the database to do that. But two transactions might both read the same value concurrently, and then incrementing it. You would thus have a duplicate. Using a lock in the table row holding the next number allows avoiding this situation.

Comment: Thanks guys for your valuable comments and contributions. I was away for last two weeks, hence couldn't respond earlier. Thanks again from my end.